# Automapper first IQueryable.ProjectTo projection is too slow

Tags: performance, entity-framework, automapper

I have Dto classes:

```
public class PackageDto
{
    public MemberDto Receiver { get; set; }
    public MemberDto Sender { get; set; }
    public DocflowDto Docflow { get; set; }

    public DocflowTypeOption DocflowTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public Guid? DocGuid { get; set; }
}

public class LightPackageDto
{
    public DocflowDto Docflow { get; set; }
    public DocflowTypeOption DocflowTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public Guid? DocGuid { get; set; }        
}

public class MemberDto
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public EntityTypeOption Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
    public string Prop4 { get; set; }
    public string Prop5 { get; set; }
    public PersonDto Director { get; set; }
    public string CompanyShortName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyFullName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyPrefix { get; set; }
}
```

DocflowDto has 3 simple type properties and is projected by flattening. 
PersonDto has 3 simple type properties and is projected by flattening too

Mapping rules:

```
        CreateMap<Person, PersonDto>();
        CreateMap<Member, MemberDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Prop1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Employee.Prop1))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Prop2, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Prop2))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Prop3, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Employee.Prop3))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Prop4, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Employee.Prop4))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Prop5, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Employee.Prop5))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Director, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Employee.Director))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CompanyShortName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Company.CompanyShortName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CompanyFullName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Company.CompanyFullName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CompanyPrefix, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Company.Prefix))
            ;
        CreateMap<Data.Models.Docflow.Package, PackageDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Sender, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Sender))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Receiver, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Receiver))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Docflow, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Docflow))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.DocGuid, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Files.FirstOrDefault().DocGuid))
            ;



        CreateMap<Data.Models.Docflow.Package, LightPackageDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Docflow, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Docflow))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.DocGuid, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Files.FirstOrDefault().DocGuid));
```

Then tests:

```
//fast
        var lightEntity = await _db.Packages.Where(p => p.PackageGuid == packageGuid).ProjectTo<LightPackageDto>().FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        //fast (_db.GetPackage make query with all necessary includes)
        var entity = await _db.GetPackage(packageGuid);
        var entityDto = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Package, PackageDto>(entity);

        //first run too slow
        var result = await _db.Packages.AsNoTracking().Where(p => p.PackageGuid == packageGuid).ProjectTo<PackageDto>().FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

1) So if I project to LightPackageDto (without Member projections) is all right.

2) If I return entity manually from EF with includes and then I make mappings for "in memory" entity is all right too

3) If I want Automapper makes "Select" query applying ProjectTo I allways get freeze about 2-3 sec. But freeze appears only single first time. Why?

And additional question. I see in result sql select statement all the columns of all the concerning tables. I supposed to see only columns needed for destination projection. Why are all there?

Comment: Try the [MyGet](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/The-MyGet-build.html) build.

Comment: I've tried. Not correct behavior saved ((

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: First projection is slow. Next are fast. Here the gist https://gist.github.com/VitMosin/c0f32ba5f1589584b32999451cf547e4

Comment: Thanks for the repro. I don't see anything wrong with the expression AM generates. But I see a lot of outer joins. So I'm guessing in your app the time is spent fetching things from the DB.

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain how to see AM expressions? And main question I wonder is why result2 expression is long calculated first time, but second time is calculated instantly (in debug). Why?

Comment: See [this](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Understanding-your-mapping.html). Most things are slower on the first run. AM, EF and SQL Server all do extra things for the first call. In this case, I'd say it's EF and SQL, but you have to profile it to know for sure. In your repro, it's creating the DB. In real life, it would be the query, because all those outer joins. But you need to measure.

Comment: By diagnostic tools I defined many exceptions in EF core and System.Core. And I think it's a root of low productivity

Comment: @VitalyMosin Have you found the source of this issue?  I am running into an identical problem.  The first call to `ProjectTo` is crazy slow. The query itself is fast, only once I add the mapping is it slowed down.  I am also eager compiling my mappings at application startup, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Or do you know if there is a way to pre-cache whatever is causing the slow down?  It freezes my UI for 10 seconds on the first run...

Answer (score -1):

It is just some stupid bug. It is not caching or anything. Because touching the intended projection and canceling the task is enough to "clean the path" (solution 1). Or (sometimes) converting query to list before getting first element also works (solution 2).

### Solution 1:

Works every time for me. (Note that the time (1000 ms in this case) starts counting when `CancelAfter` method is hit. So debugging step-by-step jumps to `catch` block almost every time.)

```cs
CancellationTokenSource cancelationTokenSource  = new CancellationTokenSource();
cancelationTokenSource.CancelAfter(1000);
PackageDto result = null;
 
try
 {
   result = await _db.Packages.AsNoTracking()
   .Where(p => p.PackageGuid == packageGuid).ProjectTo<PackageDto>()
   .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancelationTokenSource.Token);//cancel this, when taking longer than 1s
 }
 catch (OperationCanceledException)
 { //do absolutely the same thing, but now it will be fast... 
  result = await _db.Packages.AsNoTracking()
   .Where(p => p.PackageGuid == packageGuid).ProjectTo<PackageDto>()
   .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
 }
```

#### Solution 2:

!!! Doesn't work consistently. Need some more investigation

```cs
PackageDto result = await _db.Packages.AsNoTracking()
  .Where(p => p.PackageGuid == packageGuid).ProjectTo<PackageDto>()
  .ToList().FirstOrDefault();//converting to list for some reason helps here..
```

Yeah. Not the most beautiful solution, but better than waiting 25 seconds...

(btw .net6, Automapper 10.1.1, AutoMapper.Collection.EntityFrameworkCore 7.1.3)